# res.sendStatus() in async block

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to send back a success code inside a async block and I am getting an error: `Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

```
stripe.charges.create({
    amount: booking.currentPrice,
    currency: "usd",
    source: "tok_visa_debit",
    destination: {
      account: booking.hostUser.stripeAccountId,
    },
}).then(function(charge, err) {
    // asynchronously called
    res.sendStatus(200); // causes error
});

res.sendStatus(500);
```

How can I indicate success inside this async block?

Comment: You can't `res.sendStatus()` twice. Either send 500 or 200, but don't send 500 _and then_ 200.

Comment: You forgot to wrap `res.sendStatus(500);` in a catch callback.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are sending the 500 status regardless of the outcome, which means it is probably sent before the success handler is called.

You should only send the error status in case of an error.

```
stripe.charges.create({
    amount: booking.currentPrice,
    currency: "usd",
    source: "tok_visa_debit",
    destination: {
        account: booking.hostUser.stripeAccountId,
    },
}).then(function(charge) {
        // asynchronously called
        res.sendStatus(200); // causes error
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
}) ;
```

Comment: Except that `then()` doesn't accept two arguments in the callback, and `catch()` requires a callback parameter...

Comment: Thanks, I  actually don't know this API.

Comment: The API is called a `Promise`, it's pretty standard.

Comment: Remove the `err` argument from `.then()` and I'll upvote.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I thought it was possible the `then` handler would pass an error in case there was actually was one.

Comment: Yes but the signature for that is `.then(function (charge) { ... }, function (error) { ... })`